# Bind registered name to component instance in structuremap

Tags: structuremap

I am about to switch from Windsor to Structuremap for an existing project with ~100 registered components (mostly singletons). 
All components inherit from a common base class that provides logging and health tracking and for this reason, contains a "Name" property used to identify component instances.

With Windsor, it was possible to set the component's Name property to the name that was used to register the component in the IOC container (We used a Facility for this).

My question: Is something like this possible with Structuremap?

(I dream of a call to `c.For<IFoo>.Use<Bar>.Named("Doe")` that magically results in `instanceOfBar.Name = "Doe"` somewhere.)

Here is what I tried:

```
using System;
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Interceptors;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    interface IServiceA { }

    interface IServiceB { }

    class Base
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class ComponentA : Base, IServiceA { }

    class ComponentB : Base, IServiceB
    {
        public ComponentB(IServiceA serviceA)
        {
            this.ServiceA = serviceA;
        }

        public IServiceA ServiceA { get; private set; }
    }

    class SetNameInterceptor : TypeInterceptor
    {
        public bool MatchesType(Type type) { return true; }

        public object Process(object target, IContext context)
        {
            // *** Any other way? This does not work...
            string name = context.BuildStack.Current != null ? context.BuildStack.Current.Name : context.RequestedName;
            ((Base)target).Name = name;
            return target;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Container container = new Container(c =>
            {
                c.RegisterInterceptor(new SetNameInterceptor());
                c.For<IServiceA>().Use<ComponentA>().Named("A");
                c.For<IServiceB>().Use<ComponentB>().Named("B");
            });

            var b = container.GetInstance<IServiceB>();

            // both Fail:
            Debug.Assert(((ComponentB)b).Name == "B"); 
            Debug.Assert(((ComponentA)((ComponentB)b).ServiceA).Name == "A");
        }
    }
}
```

The above obviously does not work, I tried several variations but had no luck. The registered name of the target object does not seem to be consistently reachable via `IContext`.

My second best approach would be to define a new "NamedComponent(...)" extension method that resolves to `Named(name).WithProperty(x => x.Name).EqualTo(name)`, but I wonder if this can be avoided to keep component registration as "structuremap-like" as possible?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used WithProperty before but if it works the way I'd expect it *should* do the trick for you.

I think I would favor using EnrichWith though.  Something like:

```
c.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>().Named(name).EnrichWith(f => f.Name = name);
```

EnrichWith is a bit more explicit about what it's doing IMO, and lets you call any code on your instance before returning it to the caller.  I like that this lets you do a straightforward assignment as well.

There is also a more complex handler you can use with EnrichWith that gives access to the context of the request - this would allow you to do something like this:

```
c.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>().Named(name)
    .EnrichWith((c, i) => {
        i.Name = c.RequestedName;
        return i;
    });
```

This may be overkill for your situation but the contextual awareness can be pretty useful.

Comment: Yes, `EnrichWith` really looks nice than the `WithProperty` thing - good point.

The core of my issue is the fact that `context.RequestedName` does return the name of the component that is being instantiated, but the name of the component that is being requested.

Comment: What I want to prevent is that I have to add "Enrich" to 100+ component registrations, but perhaps a custom extension method really is the way to go here. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah from that perspective I think the extension method is a cool solution - all I could help with was the implementation of that method, don't know anything that directly achieves your goal.